# iTunes upload error with Google cast 3.4.0 sdk

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode8, chromecast

While uploading on appstore, duration verifying asset this error occured

1 package(s) were not uploaded because they had problems:
    /var/folders/mc/szkcdv6110798d03q80ywn2c0000gn/T/479795DC-C2B7-4F8A-8F9D-A269F4B7792A/1015136701.itmsp - Error Messages:
        ERROR ITMS-90087: "Unsupported Architectures. The executable for AppName.app/Frameworks/GoogleCast.framework contains unsupported architectures '[x86_64, i386]'."
        ERROR ITMS-90209: "Invalid Segment Alignment. The app binary at 'AppName.app/Frameworks/GoogleCast.framework/GoogleCast' does not have proper segment alignment. Try rebuilding the app with the latest Xcode version."
        ERROR ITMS-90125: "The binary is invalid. The encryption info in the LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO load command is either missing or invalid, or the binary is already encrypted. This binary does not seem to have been built with Apple's linker.”

I am trying to run strip_unused_archs.sh script might be it is not working properly, can any one share proper way to run strip_unused_archs.sh script

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try to add it as a post-action under build configurations in the edit scheme.
This fixed it for me, when I was using Carthage.